# IE8 SCRIPT87: Invalid argument.

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, styles, loader

So I have a typical annoying without explanation IE8 error. It writes "Script87:Invalid Argument".
Here's the code:

```
    var loaded = false;
    function loader(wrapperId) {
        var Loader = document.createElement("div");
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.src = "../scripts/loader/1.gif";


        Loader.style.marginTop = ((window.innerHeight / 2) - image.height) + 5 + "px";
        //error appears right here. ^

        Loader.style.marginLeft = ((window.innerWidth / 2) - (image.width)) + 5 + "px";
        Loader.style.display = "block";


        Loader.id = "loader";
        Loader.appendChild(image);
        document.body.appendChild(Loader);


        var imLoading = setInterval(function () {
            if (loaded == true) {
                var containerLoader = document.getElementById(wrapperId);
                var loaderDivBar = document.getElementById(Loader.id);
                loaderDivBar.innerHTML = "";
                containerLoader.style.visibility = "visible";
                document.body.removeChild(loaderDivBar);
                document.body.overflow = "visible";
                clearInterval(imLoading);
            }
        }, 50);
        //place this call behind body object.
    }
```

Now, it works beautifully in EVERYTHING BUT IE8.
So here's the part it spits the error out on:

```
Loader.style.marginTop = ((window.innerHeight / 2) - image.height) + 5 + "px";
```

Comment: Console.log `window.innerHeight` just before the erranous line, what you see? The result is `undefined`, [`innerHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff974677%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was implemented in IE9 ...

Comment: You are reading the width and height of the image before it actually loads.

Comment: If you've narrowed down the error to a line, don't you think it would help if you inspected the calculation results?

Comment: When I make a console log call, IE8 indeed returns undefined.

Teemu, thank you, I did not know it was implemented in IE9, that might explain it. Any suggestions for circumvention?

Comment: @user2588440 Setting `body {height: 100%}` and retrieving `.body.getBoundingClientRect().bottom` might be a solution. ([gBCR()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getBoundingClientRect))